# Sync all gnome shell settings

Tags: gnome, sync, dropbox

I have different computers (laptop, private, work) and want to sync ALL gnome shell settings, including panels, keyboard shortcuts, gnome shell extensions, ...

My plan is to create a dropbox folder `gnome-settings` which contains all relevant files and create symlinks to the required paths. I know that settings can be dumped with `gconftool --dump ...` and then loaded with `gconftool --load ...` but I would prefer to sync the files only (if this is possible) without having to export/import any settings...

My question is now which files/folders do I have to sync.

- custom application starters: `.local/share/applications`
- custom icons : `~/.local/share/icons`
- gnome shell extensions: `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` (is it safe to just sync this folder or do the extensions have to be installed?)
- keybord shortcuts: ???
- online accounts: ???
- panels: ????
- favourite applications: ???
- default applications for certain file types: ??
- gnome shell settings : ??? (the settings from gconftool must be saved anywhere....)
- number/names/arrangement of workspaces: ???
- what else??

please help me to complete the list

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87310/synchronize-gnome-3-panel-settings-between-computers/97668#97668